# What valves are these?

Tags: road-bike, pump

What valves are these, and why do each wheel have its own type?

[image: front wheel]

[image: rear wheel]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The front one is Dunlop and the rear one is Presta. The rear rim is drilled for Schrader valve, which is thicker than Presta. I don't know the reason for this, but I suspect that whoever put the bike together just used the parts that were at hand without any planning.

Comment: Thank you. Why the rear valve is shorter? Can I replace it with a Schrader?

Comment: Prestas come in different lengths for different rims. The one you have is either too short for the rim or there is some kind of washer to provide correct sized hole that is holding the valve deep inside the rim.

Comment: I'd note that Dunlop tubes are hard to find in the US, and likely in some other parts of the world.

Comment: @Daniel I just got a Presta tube and it came with an adapter so that you can put it in a Schrader/Dunlop drilled rim.